# ExternalInterface.addCallback not working on Android for local files

Tags: android, flash

I have the following situation:

AS3 Code:

```
...
Security.allowDomain("*");
ExternalInterface.addCallback("onZoom", onZoom);
...

public function onZoom(...
```

JavaScript code:

```
...
alert(getFlashMovie("test"));
alert(getFlashMovie("test").onZoom);
...
```

And in OBJECT and EMBED tags I have `allowScriptAccess="always"`

If I test the html page from my computer ("file:///path-to-file.html") both

```
alert(getFlashMovie("test"));
alert(getFlashMovie("test").onZoom);
```

give me proper result.

If I put my html as well as my swf in my android phone sdcard and I do load it into a WebView like this...

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewMain);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
});

webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.loadUrl("file:///sdcard/test/test.html");
```

... then `alert(getFlashMovie("test").onZoom);` gives me "undefined".

If I move my html and swf to a web server, and load with `webView.loadUrl("http:/mydomain.com/test/test.html");` it works.

I did another try with this example:
http://0me.me/demo/adobeflash/ExternalInterface.call/demo.html

It works if I load it from that url, it doesn't if I copy that html file (and the relevant swf) on my sdcard.
If I copy the same file (and swf) on my computer and test it locally, there it works.

So it seems that flash player for computer allows ExternalInterface.addCallback even for local files (file:///...) whereas flash player for android 10.2 doesn't.

I didn't try installing a local web server on my android phone and loading from there so far, but I would avoid such a solution if possible.
Can someone help me please?
Thanks.

Comment: hi, any progress on this question?